# How to get similarity percentage in images using openCv?

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I used openCV library to get the similarity percentage in images . I used compareHist function of openCv library which returns double value, there different method name (int value) are passed in this function and got different- different result for every Mehod .Now how to take decision on these double values????

```
Mat src_base, hsv_base;
Mat src_test1, hsv_test1;
//  Mat src_test2, hsv_test2;
Mat hsv_half_down;

 String baseImgPath = [baseImagePath UTF8String];
String firstCmpImgPath = [firstCmpImagePath UTF8String];//compare image path



src_base = imread( baseImgPath, 1 ); read source image
src_test1 = imread(firstCmpImgPath, 1 ); read compared image
//  src_test2 = imread(secondCmpImgPath, 1 );
 if( !src_base.data ||  !src_test1.data  /*||!src_test2.data*/)
{
 return nil;
 }

 cvtColor( src_base, hsv_base, COLOR_BGR2HSV );
cvtColor( src_test1, hsv_test1, COLOR_BGR2HSV );
//cvtColor( src_test2, hsv_test2, COLOR_BGR2HSV );

hsv_half_down = hsv_base( Range( hsv_base.rows/2, hsv_base.rows - 1 ), Range( 0,       hsv_base.cols - 1 ) );

/// Using 50 bins for hue and 60 for saturation
int h_bins = 50; int s_bins = 60;
int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };

// hue varies from 0 to 179, saturation from 0 to 255
 float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
 float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };

 const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };

 // Use the o-th and 1-st channels
 int channels[] = { 0, 1 };


 /// Histograms
  MatND hist_base;
 MatND hist_half_down;
 MatND hist_test1;
 MatND hist_test2;

 /// Calculate the histograms for the HSV images
 calcHist( &hsv_base, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_base, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
 normalize( hist_base, hist_base, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

 calcHist( &hsv_half_down, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_half_down, 2, histSize, ranges,  true, false );
 normalize( hist_half_down, hist_half_down, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  calcHist( &hsv_test1, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_test1, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
  normalize( hist_test1, hist_test1, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );


 for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
 {
  int compare_method = i;

 double base_test1 = compareHist( hist_base, hist_test1, compare_method );
 }

       compare method are CV_COMP_CORREL, CV_COMP_CHISQR , CV_COMP_INTERSECT ,  CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA 
  Reference link http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of decision do you want to take? You want to decide whether an image belongs to a certain class ?

Comment: I want to know the differnce percentage between the original image and other image which is similar to the original image but have some difference......... We can do so by using bitmap but i want to do it by using histogram like photo sweeper application is doing...

Answer (score 2):

For a bitmap it makes sense to define a similarity metric that computes the percentage of pixels in an image that are different from a target image.

However when you are using the histogram of a bitmap/image this metric looses sense because you already made a **statistic** on that image (*or extracted a feature*). From this point, to compute the similarity, you compare the features of the 2 images, in your case with **compareHist**.

A higher distance means a more different image and 0 distance could mean that the images are 100% identical. Now it depends if the algorithm can actually output 0. However a 0.5 distance does not mean that the images are identical 50%.

However you can artificially **create** a similarity degree measured in percentage. You can consider the following:

- The 2 images with the lowest similarity degree between them (*maximum distance*) have 0% similarity; You can even compute this distance using one pure black image and one pure white image :)
- Distance 0 is similarity 100%.

Based on these assumptions, you can extract the similarity measured in percentage, based on your **computeHist** distance.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html                                      Above link describe the histogram comparison but I am unable to reach to conclusion from its result......

Comment: Thanks VAndrei for your response ... It looks like "Hit and Try" method if compared image comparison result lies in threshold value that the image is similar ... but can we get the similarity in percentage using this –

Comment: Thanks for your Response.... VAndrei. According to your if  Chi-square method or Bhattacharyya method is applied and if the resultant is near to zero then the images are similar (almost similar)
According to you : A higher distance means a more different image and 0 distance means that the images are 100% identical.

Comment: That makes sense. The best idea would be giving as arguments 2 identical images and compute the Chi-square and Bhattacharyya distances. Then you will find the distance where images are 100% identical. To find the 0% similarity spot you could use one black image compared to one white image.

Comment: Is it necessary to input one Black and one white image to get 0% similarity....Can we get 0% similarity in colored images (which are different)

Comment: I suggested B/W image as you are sure that all pixels are completely different. You can try with colored images but the chance of getting similar pixels would be higher.

Comment: Hi VAndrei still I was unable to get the similarity percentage exactly same as Photo Sweeper app is doing . So Can you help me out of this........... Thanks in advance.    I am using "Bhattacharyya" distance formula to get the similarity in images if the images are identical i am getting the result as 0 but if not then I subtract the result from unit and calculate the percentage.       http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2012/04/find-duplicate-photos-in-your-iphoto-library-with-photosweeper.html

Comment: If you compare a black image with a white one, what distance do you get? Are you sure that PhotoSweeper uses also "Bhattacharyya" ?

Comment: I am not sure that PhotoSweeper using "Bhattacharyya"....Even I am not sure that it is using OpenCv library .... and I am comparing two screen shots by converting them in 48x48 thumbnail.. and there comparssion result is "0.1031229738684974". These two images are almost same having little bit of difference in there base and both are colored images

Comment: I attached the two images above in Question these images are converted into 48x48 thumbnail and there resultant is given above.. According to PhotoSweeper there is no similarity in these images... but if more text added to these images then it will show unto 95-98 % similarity in them

Comment: I have attached two more images and PhotoSweeper shows 95.7% similarity between them and I am getting "0.1153843569993133" using "Bhattacharyya"

Comment: If you compare a pure black image with a pure white image what distance/similarity do you get? Using your method and PhotoSweeper?